# How can I use a variable in website link using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, whatsapp, python-webbrowser

I want to send *WhatsApp* messages to numbers without adding them contact using Python.

`webbrowser.open('https://api.WhatsApp.com/send?phone=number')`

I used upper code in my program but Ii want to ask that, I am making a TkInter project, in my program `cph` is phone number variable and I also called `cph.get()` function but how can I use this `cph` variable in this link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your link before opening it.

```
link = "https://api.WhatsApp.com/send?phone=" + variable
webbrowser.open(link)
```